# Compilation Error : CS0308 The non-generic type 'PermissionChecker' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

After upgrading NuGet packages to `v2.1.3`, I am getting this error on compilation:

> Error : CS0308    The non-generic type 'PermissionChecker' cannot be used
>   with type arguments

I am using an ASP.NET Boilerplate template.

Project: `MembershipMgmt.Core`

Class: `MembershipMgmt.Authorization.PermissionChecker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that this is a breaking change and Code inthe PermissionChecker class needs to be modified as

```
public class PermissionChecker : PermissionChecker<Role, User>
{
    public PermissionChecker(UserManager userManager)
        : base(userManager)
    {

    }
}
```